# Inheritance - UIAlertView in superclass and subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, delegates, uialertview

I have a superclass where I sometimes show an UIAlertView and handles the delegation (clickedButtonAtIndex).
When I then have a subclass that also handles the "clickedButtonAtIndex" only the subclass delegation is called.

In both cases the UIAlertView is show like this:

```
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Open", nil]show];
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it bad design to have the same delegation in both the superclass and subclass. I thought the "delegate:self" separated them.

I can see in the debugger that "self" references to my subclass even though I'm in my superclass so this is probably the problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: if you want to invoke the superclass' method from within the subclass, call `[super alertView:alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:buttonIndex];`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but then I need to expose the method in the superclass. And call it in ALL my subclasses. It seems a bit overkill and not the right design?

Comment: Are you targeting ios 8? If so you should be using uialertcontroller.

Comment: No, targetting iOS 7.

Comment: When a subclass overrides a method and that subclass method also needs the super class to be run then you must call super. You have no choice. If the subclass has no additional functionality for the method them don't override the method. If the subclass does have special needs for the method and it doesn't want the functionality of the superclass, then don't call super.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts rmaddy. I've answered my own question with what I've decided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was kind of surprised that 'self' references to the subclass when called in a superclass.

Thus I decided to create my own delegation for the UIAlertView to distinguish from the subclass' delegation. This because I dont think:
- That the subclasses should know about my private UIAlertView in the superclass and call it.
- That the superclass should know about my subclasses delegation.

Feel free to add you thoughts :-)